Convert a dataframe with lists to a dictionary
I have a dataframe that contains a identifier and list in each cell. The idea is to create a dictionary in which the keys are the identifiers and the values are a list with the elements that appears in the dataframe. Identifiers may repeat with different lists so they must be combined for the dictionary. Eg.
   id    col1          
0  a  ['val1', 'val2']
1  b  ['val2', 'val3']
2  c  ['val1']
3  c  ['val5', 'val6']

Desired:
{'a': ['val1', 'val2'], 'b': ['val2', 'val3'], 'c': ['val1', 'val5', 'val6']}

How to do that?

You can flatten nested lists in lambda function with itertools.chain and last convert Series by Series.to_dict:
import ast, itertools

#if necessary
#df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

d = df.groupby('id')['col1'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain(*x))).to_dict()
print (d)
{'a': ['val1', 'val2'], 'b': ['val2', 'val3'], 'c': ['val1', 'val5', 'val6']}

Or with list comprehension:
d = df.groupby('id')['col1'].apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).to_dict()

Or with DataFrame.explode if performance is not important:
d = df.explode('col1').groupby('id')['col1'].apply(list).to_dict()

